# Rails Convert String to Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, type-conversion, rake-task

I created a rake task which is reading data from a csv file. It is reading the rows as strings. I have a description column in the table I am populating which is of type text.

I am wondering how to convert the string from the csv file to text so that the column will accept the data.

Thank you very much. The help is greatly appreciated as ruby and rails are still very new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No conversion is needed!

Ruby does not see a difference between 'string' and 'text', only some databases do.

Just set the attribute on your object to the value from the CSV file and save it.

Comment: No problem. It's worth noting that Rails will usually try to run conversions for any data you're saving without your help. So, for instance, if someone types a number into a form, it will be transferred to the database as a string (e.g. "1234"), but if you save "1234" to an integer column, it will be saved as an integer.